# Is an ObservableCollection that implements IListSource advisable for EF 6 navigation properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am just getting started with Entity Framework and I am using EF 6.1.3 in a Windows Forms application that targets .Net 4.5.2 (no particular reason why it can't be a later .Net version).

I want to bind my data to a Windows Forms `DataGridView`, and I found this walkthrough on MSDN [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682076(v=vs.113).aspx). The page was last updated in October 2016, but appears to be older (it implies that Visual Studio 2013 is the latest version).

The page suggests creating an `ObservableListSource` class that inherits from `ObservableCollection` and implements `IListSource` (the `IListSource.Getlist` implementation simply returns an `IList` created by calling `ToBindingList` on the `ObservableCollection`), like this:

```
public class ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource
    where T : class
{
    private IBindingList _bindingList;

    bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection { get { return false; } }

    IList IListSource.GetList()
    {
        return _bindingList ?? (_bindingList = this.ToBindingList());
    }
}
```

It then suggests changing the type of the navigation properties in POCO (entity) classes that point to child entities from `IList` or `ICollection` to `ObservableListSource`, like this:

```
public class Category
{
    private readonly ObservableListSource<Product> _products =
            new ObservableListSource<Product>();

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableListSource<Product> Products { get { return _products; } }
}
```

My `DataGridView` *appeared* to be working when my navigation properties were declared as `IList`, but it's possible I haven't tested all aspects yet. My question is **is there any benefit in EF 6/.Net 4.5 of having navigation properties with a type that is an `ObservableCollection` that implements `IListSource`** or is that a workaround that was required in earlier versions?

I realise that I could just go ahead and create the `ObservableListSource` class and use it for all my navigation properties, but I don't want to complicate my code with something that isn't necessary (and might lead to problems down the road).

Comment: Can't believe what I read there. Like it's a DAL's only task to bind entities to DGVs. Even if it is today, it won't be tomorrow. Loose coupling is a key to stable software. Unless it's going to be a narrow-scoped, short-lived app, don't even bind entities to the UI. Use view models.

Comment: @GertArnold I can see why that would make sense, but does using a view model solve some problem that the `ObservableListSource` class is trying to address, or has that problem already been addressed?